# Multi part if statement

Tags: python-3.x

no really sure how to complete this as I ave tried and it fails.

```
 result = ['GigabitEthernet0/1', 'GigabitEthernet0/2']
 unused_interface = 'GigabitEthernet0/3'

 unused_interface not in result:
     if unused_interface != False:
        if unused_interface != 'show':
```

The above works but it horrible, the below is what I presumed I needed but doesn't work.

```
 unused_interface not in result or unused_interface != False or unused_interface != 'show':
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: you need and instead of or

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I didn't think of it.